# Pandas: get string from specific column header

Tags: python, pandas

Context:

i am new in Pandas and I need a function that creates new columns based on existing columns. The new columns name will have the name from the original column plus new characters (example: create a "As NEW" column from "As" column).
Can i access the old column header string to make the name of the new column?

Problem:

i have `df['columnA']` and need to get `"columnA"` string

Comment: Please provide what you already tried.

Comment: @scharette i didn't figured out any code, but edited the question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may be what you're looking for.

You can use [str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for the columns, then use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) to create the new column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'A', 'B','B'], 'As': ['B','B','C','C'], 'col2': ['C','C','A','A'], 'col3': [30,10,14,91]})
col = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('As')]
df['%s New' % col[0]] = 'foo'
print (df)
   As   col1 col2  col3 As New
0  B    A    C    30    foo
1  B    A    C    10    foo
2  C    B    A    14    foo
3  C    B    A    91    foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an empty DataFrame `df` with columns, you could access the columns of `df` as a list with:

```
 >>> df.columns
Index(['columnA', 'columnB'], dtype='object')
```

`.columns` will allow you to overwrite the columns of `df`, but you don't need to pass in another `Index`. You can pass it a regular list, like so:

```
>>> df.columns = ['columna', 'columnb']
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [columna, columnb]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the columns attribute.

```
cols = df.columns
# Do whatever operation you want on the list of strings in cols
df.columns = cols
```